# Autocomplete selected value - Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Jquery code:

```
   var prefixes = [{
        "name": "Estonia",
        "dial_code": "+372",
        "code": "EE"
      }, {
        "name": "Latvia",
        "dial_code": "+371",
        "code": "LV"
      }, {
        "name": "Lithuania",
        "dial_code": "+370",
        "code": "LT"
      }, {
        "name": "Finland",
        "dial_code": "+358",
        "code": "FI"
      }, {
        "name": "Sweden",
        "dial_code": "+46",
        "code": "SE"
      }];

      prefixes = $.map(prefixes, function(item, i) {
        return {
          label: item.name + " " + item.dial_code,
          value: item.dial_code
        };
      });

          $('.js-phone-prefix input').autocomplete({
            delay: 0,
            minLength: 0,
            source: prefixes,
            appendTo: $('.js-phone-prefix')
          }).focus(function() {
            $(this).autocomplete('search', $(this).val())
          }).each(function() {
            $(this).autocomplete("widget").addClass("phone-prefix");
          });
```

HTML Code:

```
<div class="js-phone-prefix small" style="position: relative;">
  <input type="text" name="prefix" id="prefix" value="">
</div>
```

What I am trying is that when user selects one of the options from the list I want to set that value as input value. for example if user selects "Estonia" the input value has to be +372. Any suggestions?  [link to fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/L4gz0mwe/1/)

Comment: For me it seems to work exactly as you want it to. I click the input, and it displays a list. I select "Estonia", and get +372.

Comment: yes but value doesn't contains anything I don't know why

Comment: For me the value contains the correct code: http://fiddle.jshell.net/6wc5r30h/

Comment: @Anders Yes but he want to add it on value of input

Comment: @zlen exatly thats my problem

Comment: The value attribute always holds the initial value -- in this case`""`  from `value=""` -- and does not change when the value property is changed via jQuery's `val()` method or JS's `this.value = 'new value'`. **YOU MUST CHANGE THE ATTRIBUTE EXPLICITLY `$(this).attr('value', 'new value')`**.

Comment: @zlen can you update fiddle?

Comment: @fishera : Delighted to have helped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [**documentation**](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select), you have to bind an event when you select the option on the autocomplete.

```
$(".selector").autocomplete({
  select: function(e, ui) {
    // Code will be placed here
  }
});
```

So in your example, you have to add this to the code above :`ui.item.value` is the object of your value).

```
select: function(e, ui) {
  $(e.target).attr({'value' : ui.item.value});
}
```

Please see the [**JSFIDDLE**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/L4gz0mwe/2/) updated

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.js-phone-prefix input').autocomplete({
    //...

    select: function( event, ui ){
        $(event.target).val(ui.item.value);
        console.log($('.ui-autocomplete-input').val());
    },

    //...
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/6wc5r30h/2/

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select